# .map() through array of object in next.js does not display in html but in console?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am not able to display the elements of this array in html. I am fetching data from the Bscscan api. I can fetch perfectly from the first api but the second does not show the data in the local browser. I will show you all the code I've got.

I added also pictures of what the browser looks like and my terminal. It looks like i cannot map through arrays with objects, but I have tried everything change the object into react readable content, and nothing worked, so I will show you the code I started with. The Address 2 is the problem address.

Code :

```js
import Head from 'next/head'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
import React from 'react'


export default function Home(props) {



  const datatransone  =  props.addresstransaction;
  const databalone = props.addressbalance;

  //something wrong with stringify
  // const datatransone = JSON.stringify(datatransjson);

  console.log(databalone);
  console.log(datatransone);

  return  (
    <ul>      
      <h1>Address One</h1>
      {databalone.map((balance) => {
        return (
      <li>{(balance.result * 1e-18).toString()}</li>
      )})}
      <div>
      <h1>Address Two</h1>
      <div>
      {datatransone.map(function(d){
         return (<li key={d.hash}>{d.result.hash}</li>)
       })}
      </div>
      </div>
    </ul>
  );
}


export async function getServerSideProps(context) {

    let wlunarush = ['0xb4e856c2a257457b862daed14967578bbdba3526', '0x52ab04656c807a3af96f98e4428291e813c2687a'];
    // let contractaddress = '0xde301D6a2569aEfcFe271B9d98f318BAee1D30a4';
  

    let balance = wlunarush.map(function(element){

      let bscbalance = 'https://api-testnet.bscscan.com/api?module=account&action=tokenbalance&contractaddress=0x0DBfd812Db3c979a80522A3e9296f9a4cc1f5045&address=' + element + '&tag=latest&apikey=E2JAJX6MAGAZUHSYIBZIEMKMNW9NZKPR7I';

    return bscbalance;
  })

    let transaction = wlunarush.map(function(element){

      let bsctransaction = 'https://api-testnet.bscscan.com/api?module=account&action=tokentx&contractaddress=0x0DBfd812Db3c979a80522A3e9296f9a4cc1f5045&address=' + element + '&page=1&startblock=0&offset=1&endblock=999999999&sort=asc&apikey=E2JAJX6MAGAZUHSYIBZIEMKMNW9NZKPR7I';

    return bsctransaction;
  })



    const addressbalance = await Promise.all(balance.map(u => fetch(u)))
    const addresstransaction = await Promise.all(transaction.map(e => fetch(e)))


  // console.log(bscbalancelist)
  // console.log(bscbalancelist);
  // const responsesec = await fetch(transaction);
  // const bscbalancelist = await bscbalone.json();


  return {
    props: {
      addressbalance:  await Promise.all(addressbalance.map(r => r.json())),
      addresstransaction:  await Promise.all(addresstransaction.map(p => p.json())),
    }
  };


}
```

[Console.log in Terminal :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNhzJ.png)

[Browser :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KAUn.png)

Comment: `d.result` is an array of objects, not an object. You can't access the `hash` value without specifying which element in the array you want to use like `d.result[0].hash`

Comment: Please do not edit your question with the answer. If you solved the problem you can post an answer to your own question below.

Comment: Oh ok will do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a nested array, so you will need to use a nested `map` in order to iterate over all items.

I've simplified a bit, but you should be able to get the idea and adapt it to match your exact needs.

```js
function Home() {

  const databalone = [{status: '1', message: 'OK', result: '1234'},{status: '1', message: 'OK', result: '1234'}];
  const datatransone = [{status: '1', message: 'OK', result: [{hash: '4321'}]},{status: '1', message: 'OK', result: [{hash: '54321'}]}];

  return  (
    <ul>      
      <h1>Address One</h1>
      {databalone.map((balance) => {
        return (
      <li>{(balance.result * 1e-18).toString()}</li>
      )})}
      <div>
      <h1>Address Two</h1>
      <div>
      {datatransone.map(function(d){
         return (<li>{d.result.map((r) => <span>{r.hash}</span>)}</li>)
       })}
      </div>
      </div>
    </ul>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Home />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, that's a better solution!

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I had to use the index to specify what array I wanted to .map().

```js
import Head from 'next/head'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
import React from 'react'


export default function Home(props) {



  const datatransone  =  props.addresstransaction;
  const databalone = props.addressbalance;

  var transactionarray = datatransone[0];
  // var newgotwo = datatransone[1];




  // console.log(databalone);
  // console.log(datatransone);

  return  (
    <ul>      
      <h1>Address One</h1>
      {databalone.map((balance) => {
        return (
      <li>{(balance.result * 1e-18).toString()}</li>
      )})}
      <div>
      <h1>Address Two</h1>
      <div>
        {transactionarray.result.map(function(d){
         return (<li key={d.hash}>{d.hash}</li>)
       })}
        {/* {newgotwo.result.map(function(d){
         return (<li key={d.hash}>{d.hash}</li>)
       })} */}
      </div>
      </div>
    </ul>
  );
}


export async function getServerSideProps(context) {

    let wlunarush = ['0xb4e856c2a257457b862daed14967578bbdba3526', '0x52ab04656c807a3af96f98e4428291e813c2687a'];
    // let contractaddress = '0xde301D6a2569aEfcFe271B9d98f318BAee1D30a4';
  

    let balance = wlunarush.map(function(element){

      let bscbalance = 'https://api-testnet.bscscan.com/api?module=account&action=tokenbalance&contractaddress=0x0DBfd812Db3c979a80522A3e9296f9a4cc1f5045&address=' + element + '&tag=latest&apikey=E2JAJX6MAGAZUHSYIBZIEMKMNW9NZKPR7I';

    return bscbalance;
  })

    let transaction = wlunarush.map(function(element){

      let bsctransaction = 'https://api-testnet.bscscan.com/api?module=account&action=tokentx&contractaddress=0x0DBfd812Db3c979a80522A3e9296f9a4cc1f5045&address=' + element + '&page=1&startblock=0&offset=1&endblock=999999999&sort=asc&apikey=E2JAJX6MAGAZUHSYIBZIEMKMNW9NZKPR7I';

    return bsctransaction;
  })



    const addressbalance = await Promise.all(balance.map(u => fetch(u)))
    const addresstransaction = await Promise.all(transaction.map(e => fetch(e)))


  // console.log(addresstransaction)
  // console.log(addressbalance);
  // const responsesec = await fetch(transaction);
  // const bscbalancelist = await bscbalone.json();


  return {
    props: {
      addressbalance:  await Promise.all(addressbalance.map(r => r.json())),
      addresstransaction:  await Promise.all(addresstransaction.map(p => p.json())),
    }
  };


}
```

Comment: Does this actually do what you need? With this code you can only ever get the first element of the transaction array. Your screenshot show there are two elements currently

Comment: It was the step I needed to continue. But I would be happy when u have a way to iterate through the array and then map one index after the other. I am currently trying achieving this with the forEach .